# Geometry Transformation in Spatialite 4.1.1

Tags: spatialite

I am trying to transform a geometry (geo referenced to Australia)

> POLYGON((-33.917172 151.110971,-33.916443 151.112495,-33.917637
>   151.113276,-33.917783 151.111512,-33.917253 151.111577,-33.917172 151.110971))

from SRID 4326 to 3112 using the following query:

```
SELECT AsText(Transform(PolygonFromText('POLYGON((-33.917172 151.110971,-33.916443 151.112495,-33.917637 151.113276,-33.917783 151.111512,-33.917253 151.111577,-33.917172 151.110971))',4326),3112)) as result
```

in SpatiaLite GUI 1.7.1 with SpatiaLite 4.1.1 with all GEOS,PROJ extensions enabled but the resulting geometry is

> POLYGON((Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf))

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've got the geometry coordinates in the wrong order. Well Known Text (WKT) for SRID 4326 uses Longitude then Latitude (think Cartesian coordinates X-Y). As such, you're passing in latitudes more than 90 degrees.

So the operation should be:

```
spatialite> SELECT AsText(Transform(PolygonFromText('POLYGON((151.110971 -33.917172,151.112495 -33.916443,151.113276 -33.917637,151.111512 -33.917783,151.111577 -33.917253,151.110971 -33.917172))',4326), 3112)) as result;
```

Which will produce:

```
POLYGON((1569305.481332 -3926985.759663, 1569455.307825 -3926925.091727, 1569508.606645 -3927065.382207, 1569345.639225 -3927059.314561, 1569359.502478 -3927002.182676, 1569305.481332 -3926985.759663))
```

Comment: so if call AsTex(geometry) in query will it return the order as in geometry or in Longitude and Latitude only ??

Comment: That is a different question - please "Ask Question" again, referencing this question if applicable.